# Values are not passing to bean class after putting jQuery click function

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I´m using `Primefaces` in one project and tryng to develop a counter to how many checkboxs are selected in `p:selectCheckboxMenu`. What I don´t understand is why I select the checkbox, they values are no passed to the `backing bean class`.

My component code is

```
<p:column style="width:35%">
    <p:selectCheckboxMenu id="selectLojas"
        value="#{relatorioVigenciaTabelaTaxasComissoesBean.filter.lojas}"
        style="display: block; width:100%;" filter="true"
        filterMatchMode="contains" converter="lojaConverter">
        <f:selectItems var="loja" itemLabel="#{loja.id} - #{loja.nomeFantasia}"
            value="#{relatorioVigenciaTabelaTaxasComissoesBean.helper.lojas}" />
    </p:selectCheckboxMenu>
    <p:outputLabel id="qtdLojasLabel"/>
</p:column>
```

Below is my `jQuery` function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', 'div.ui-corner-all', function() {
                $('label[id*="qtdLojasLabel"]').text($('li.ui-selectcheckboxmenu-checked').length + ' loja(s) selecionada(s)');                 
            });
</script>
```

So why it happens? I don´t know if the problem is about scope of my class but I want to understand.

Thanks

Comment: put your jquery code inside `documet.ready()` block.

Comment: jQuery runs on the client (Browser) while your backing bean lives on the Server. How should the server know of a change in the client? I think you need to work with something like `remoteCommand`

Comment: @tilois thanks for your answer, but I´m looking to learn also `jQuery`. `remoteCommand` is from `Primafaces` ok?

Comment: @Kartikeya I put my code inside, and nothing changed. I selected the values but didn´t change the value.

Comment: @Kartikeya: OP's using `$.on()` as available since jQuery 1.7 which is released almost 3 years ago already. Keep yourself up to date and stop suggesting prehistoric approaches.

Comment: @user3503888 You won't be able to solve the problem in jQuery alone. jQuery can make the client do all kind of things, but it can't change values on the server. The server needs to offer the client a way to change it's internal values. `remotecommand` (http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/remoteCommand.html) offers such a way. If you absolutely want to avoid it, you would have to offer another way - like another servlet... but then you would have to get to the bean in question which is handled by JSF all by yourself. I really wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: @tilois I want to select every checkbox and `count` then. So if I want to implement using `jQuery` I need to implement a new component?